# Dependency tree in Android Gradle libraries

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build a tree of modular dependencies in an Android project. The structure I am aiming at is something like:

```
Project/
    -> Module1
       --> Module3
    -> Module2
    -> Module4
       --> Module3
       --> Module5
```

So project depends on some Android modules, which in turn can depend on other Android modules. Some of the modules should be shareable between parent modules.

I have tries several approaches, like:

- using the `subprojects` method in gradle

  - this seemed to have no result, as in the child module was not being detected
- having a settings.gradle file for the parent modules, which would define the child dependencies

  - it gives me a compilation error in build.gradle, as if the settings.gradle file was not detected.

Any tips would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. Gradle (and Android) support multi project builds. Please add details about what you tried (think samples) and what went wrong (think error messages with stack traces)